# C compiler cannot create executables error 77

Tags: c, makefile

When I compile the makefile this error appears

```
root@akshay-HP-ENVY-m6-Notebook-PC:/home/akshay/Downloads/FVCOM3.2.2/FVCOM_source/libs# make

for item in proj        julian      fproj   ; do (./untar.sh $item ) || exit 1; done

cd proj && ./configure CC=icc CFLAGS=-O3 CXX=icc CXXFLAGS=-O3 F77=ifort FFLAGS=-O3 --prefix=/home/akshay/Downloads/FVCOM3.2.2/FVCOM_source/libs/install

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c

checking whether build environment is sane... yes

checking for gawk... no

checking for mawk... mawk

checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes

checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no

checking for gcc... icc

checking for C compiler default output file name... configure: error: C 
compiler cannot create executables

See `config.log' for more details.

make: *** [all] Error 77
```

How to resolve this issue. I have icc installed and have checked by a test run.

Comment: Can you share the content of 'config.log'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem occurs when make is trying to run libs/proj/configure.

You should follow the installation instructions in the libs/proj/README file, which says:

> FSF's configuration procedure is used to ease installation of the
>   PROJ.4 system.
>
> The default destination path prefix for installed files is /usr/local.
>   Results from the installation script will be placed into
>   subdirectories bin, include, lib, man/man1 and man/man3.  If this
>   default path prefix is proper, then execute:
>
> ```
> ./configure
> ```
>
> If another path prefix is required, then execute:
>
> ```
> ./configure --prefix=/my/path
> ```
>
> In either case, the directory of the prefix path must exist and be
>   writable by the installer.
>
> After executing configure, execute:
>
> ```
> make install
> ```
>
> The install target will create, if necessary, all required
>   sub-directories.

Make sure your prefix path (in your case /home/akshay/Downloads/FVCOM3.2.2/FVCOM_source/libs/install) exists and is writable.

You could also try a plain configure without any options and see if the configuration script finishes successfully

```
cd proj && ./configure
```